# Can't LogIn in Steam with Steam WEB API

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, openid-connect, steam-web-api

I'm trying to create a Steam LogIn within my Blazor application. Unfortunately I get this error when calling my route for LogIn into Steam:

> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration'

I have a web assembly that calls my authentication controller via `HttpClient`:

```
@page "/steam"

@inject HttpClient HttpClient

<button @onclick="@StartSteamLogin">Start Steam login</button>

@code {

    private async Task StartSteamLogin()
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("/auth/steam-login");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. My `AuthenticationController` is handling the response and for test purpose it just redirects me to a page

```
[Route("/auth")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("steam-login")]
    public IActionResult SteamLogin()
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("SteamCallback", "SteamAuth", null, Request.Scheme);
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet("steam-callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SteamCallback()
    {
        var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        if (authenticateResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LoginFailed", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

I added a configuration to my `Program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "MYKEY";
    options.Authority = "https://steamcommunity.com/openid";
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-steam";
    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false };
});
```

Note: `MYKEY` is just a placeholder, there is actually my key in this string.

Also I'm allowing CORS and I'm using authentication and authorization

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowOrigins", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44357")
     .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader();
}));

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

When calling https://steamcommunity.com/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration in my browser, I get a file downloaded (I assume this is correct?)

Can anyone help me please?

Looking for other sources, like stackoverflow, didn't fixed my problem. I added CORS:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

which didn't solve my problem.

Edit: I tested the request with postman. With postman it works, maybe it helps someone